# Mathematical Operations

Tags: functions

Substraction is the inverse of addition
Division is the inverse of multiplication
Taking a power is the inverse of taking some root
Having an exponential is the inverse of having a logarithm

My question is if we can implement any mathematical operational using only one of the remaining operations ( but not the inverse operation ) ?
For example, can we implement addition with only multiplication ? Can we take a logaritm using only subsctraction ?

Comment: Subtraction is not technically the inverse of addition!

Comment: Why not ? Substraction is as important as addition ? Addicion is the inverse of subtraction

Comment: Technically speaking, there is not an operation substraction.
Substraction is an addition $x+(-y)$, where $-y$ is the symmetric of $y$.

Comment: Same reasoning for division.

Comment: @Integral At least where $-y$ and $y^{-1}$ are defined.

Comment: Rings axioms for $-y$ and fields axioms for $y^{-1}$. This elements must exist in this structures, and this structures are constructed with addition and multiplication operations only.

Comment: @Integral While it's true that addition $+:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ cannot be inverted, for example because $1+3=2+2$, If you take "addition" to mean an arbitrary function $+_a:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ where $+_a(x)=x+a$, then the subtraction function $-_a(x)=x-a$ is indeed its inverse.

Comment: If we are talking about arbitrary functions, then anything is possible. I dont think that is the idea of this topic.

Comment: You can't do addition with only multiplication, as multiplication is algebraically defined by addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any commutative, [semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup#Definition) $(G,\star)$ you can define the $n$-th power of an element $g\in G$ to be the shorthand $g^n=g\star\dots \star g$ ($n$-times).

Then the $n$-th powers in $(\Bbb Z, +)$ are given by multiplication by $n$ and the $n$-th powers in $(\Bbb Z\setminus\{0\},*)$ are given by exponentiation.

Moreover, if $(G,\star)$ is actually a (commutative) [group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)#Definition), then you can define an inverse to
$$
\begin{align*}
(\star g):G&\to G\\
h&\mapsto h\star g
\end{align*}
$$
by using the inverse of $g$ in $G$, i.e. $\bar{g}$ such that $g\star\bar{g}=e$
$$
\begin{align*}
(\star \bar{g}):G&\to G\\
h&\mapsto h\star \bar{g}
\end{align*}
$$

Then in our previous examples $(+(-y))$ is an inverse to (+y) in $(\Bbb Z,+)$ and $(*\frac{1}{y})$ is an inverse to $(*y)$ in $(\Bbb Q\setminus \{0\},*)$, which is the smallest group containing $(\Bbb Z\setminus\{0\},*)$.

Note that it is possible to define partial inverses in a semigroup, too, like [subtraction in $\Bbb N$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328530/is-the-set-of-natural-numbers-closed-under-subtraction/328540#328540).

Coming to your example question, the answer is no. You cannot reconstruct
$$
\star:G\times G \to G
$$
knowing only the power maps
$$
\begin{align*}
(-)^{(-)}:\Bbb Z \times G &\to G\\
(a,b) &\mapsto b^a
\end{align*}
$$
unless in some special cases, e.g when $(G,\star)$ is a cyclic group, i.e. if there is a $g\in G$ such that every $h\in G$ is of the form $h=g^n$ for some $n\in \Bbb Z$.

---

To clarify things a bit, suppose we wish to define addition in $\Bbb Z$ using multiplication. By the distributive property we get that for all $a,b,c\in \Bbb Z$
$$
ab+ac=a(b+c)
$$
hence the only possible definition is the trivial one.

---

As a side note, all this is about *algebraic* definitions of things, and in particular about defining in $\Bbb Z$ addition through multiplication or multiplication through powers. You get a somewhat different picture from the *analytical* point of view. For example, on $\Bbb R$ you can define
$$
e^x = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} {x^n \over n!} = 1 + x + {x^2 \over 2!} + {x^3 \over 3!} + {x^4 \over 4!} + \cdots
$$

Comment: I bet your explanation was really good although i'm really not acquainted with algebraic structures.Can you clarify your answear ? We can't implement addition by only multiplication although we can implement multiplication by addition ( integer-case ) ? We can't take a logaritm by using only subtraction ?

Comment: Sorry A.P .The answear is that we can't implement addition by only using multiplication ?

Comment: Yes @nerdy, unless you admit the trivial definition, which in particular means $b+'c := 1(b+c)$ if $b,c\in\Bbb Z$ are coprime, where $+'$ is the operation we are defining and $b+c$ is seen as an element of $\Bbb Z$.